# How to make this Android bubble ListView list item so the background adjusts with the text size

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-layout

How would I make a `ListView` like [this](http://cdn.zath.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/chomp-sms-android-messaging-app-screenshot.jpg) ?

I know how to make a customized `ListView`, but I do not know how to adjust the size of the background with the entered text so the text fits in the background.

Can anyone help me with tutorials or put me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5096537/593709)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice example with source code,

[Bubble ListView like Iphone](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Android-Speech-Bubble)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative layout to align your text to the right or the left, and a wrap_content value for the width or your textview