# How to develop chomp sms chat ui or whats app chat ui

Tags: android

I want UI which is something like shown in below Image.

[image]

My question is How can generate drawable which is shown behind the texts and it should be flexible enough so that varying length texts can be shown properly.

Please anyone can suggest what should i do? or any guideline ?

Comment: [does it helps you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096537/why-do-9-patch-graphics-size-correctly-in-the-emulator-but-not-on-a-phone)

Answer (score 1):

For drawables that can be expanded without distortion you should have a look at [9-Patch Images](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch). 
Those you can place in a custom ListView item along with the text you want to show.
Another good source for information about 9-patch images and how to create them: [developer.com](http://www.developer.com/ws/other/article.php/3889086/Working-with-NinePatch-Stretchable-Graphics-in-Android.htm)