# Creating a layout for a skype-style text input bubble

Tags: android, android-layout

In iPhone there is a method on UIImage called stretchableimagewithleftcapwidth which can be used to create a chat bubble to stretch for any size (keeping the corners natural size).

We don't seem to have this in Android so I've set out to make a layout that I can then use as a background image with a FrameLayout. The trouble I'm having at the moment is the top row which consists of 3 columns: the left top corner, the stretchable top, and the right top corner. How do I get the left and right top corners to remain fixed size (11dip) and tell the middle to fill any remaining space in the parent? This is what I have so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_bubble_container"
    android:orientation="vertical">    
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="11dip"
        android:id="@+id/layout_bubble_toprow"
        android:orientation="horizontal">    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_top_leftCorner"
            android:layout_width="11dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left|top">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bubble_top_leftcorner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/bubble_lefttop" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="top|center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bubble_top"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/bubble_top" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_top_rightCorner"
            android:layout_width="11dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right|top" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bubble_top_rightcorner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/bubble_righttop" />
        </LinearLayout>    
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="11dip"
        android:id="@+id/layout_bubble_middlerow"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/WHITE">    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_left"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bubble_left"
                android:layout_width="11dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/bubble_left" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_right"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right" 
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bubble_right"
                android:layout_width="11dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/bubble_right" />
        </LinearLayout>    
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="11dip"
        android:id="@+id/layout_bubble_bottomrow"
        android:orientation="horizontal">    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_leftCorner"
            android:layout_width="11dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left|top">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bubble_bottom_leftcorner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/bubble_leftbottom" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="top|center" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bubble_bottom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/bubble_bottom" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_bottom_rightCorner"
            android:layout_width="11dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right|top" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bubble_bottom_rightcorner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/bubble_rightbottom" />
        </LinearLayout>    
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the layout tree in eclipse if this helps.
[image: visualised layout]

Here is what it looks like rendered in the layout editor in eclipse. Note the top and bottom rows not stretching appropriately.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, i also needed a chat bubble kind of view in my app so I used a 9 patch drawable as the background image and it is working fine. check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096537/why-do-9-patch-graphics-size-correctly-in-the-emulator-but-not-on-a-phone

Comment: Want to chuck this into an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also needed a chat bubble kind of view in my app so I used a 9 patch drawable as the background image and it is working fine.

check this question:

[Why do 9-patch graphics size correctly in the emulator but not on a phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096537/why-do-9-patch-graphics-size-correctly-in-the-emulator-but-not-on-a-phone)

And also this link:

http://warting.se/2012/06/04/chat-bubbles-in-android/